# How to convert String of bytecode to the element from ASCII table?

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert String like "01010100" to the element from ASCII table. I should receive an answer as "T", but I don't know how to do this. :( Can you help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(char)Integer.valueOf("01010100", 2).intValue()
```

Comment: @user1238894, in case you don't know, that method takes a String representation of a number, and returns the value of it with the given base. Integer.parseInt("55"); is the same as Integer.valueOf("55", 10);